# optimized code for reversing a string in c

Tags: c, c-strings

I have always implemented the c code for reversing a string as:

1. looping I till the length of the string or till the half of its length
2. placing the pointers at the end and beginning of the string
3. swapping them one by one .

but I want an optimized code that reduces the time complexity for this problem apart from the one that I mentioned. I tried google search but did not find any relevant solution to it.

Comment: Without a length-prefix or some other way of knowing ahead of time the length, you *must* scan to find the end before doing *anything* (i.e. a `strlen()`). Once that trip is made, however, there are any number of ways to do this.

Comment: Am I the only one curious for what looping to the sqrt(len) does for solving this problem (part (c) of step #1 above)?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it's an optimization for the special case where length = 4.

Comment: The fastest way... Don't really reverse it, just read it backwards whenever it is accessed :P

Comment: @Cthulhu Now *that*, by definition, is truly optimal. **No** work beats every algorithm that does **some** work. lolz.

Comment: @WhozCraig : there are two ways to loop i.e first is to loop i variable till the sqrt(len) and second method is checking if the starting ptr has exceeded the end ptr . First method reduces the no of times loop runs (instead of going till the end of the string or its length.)

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Can you post the snippet of code? I still don't understand how looping till `sqrt(len)` could be sufficient.

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Um. looping to the sqrt(len), again, gets you *what*? Regarding a general solution in C code, you're going to get so-far before you truly need machine-level optimization (which the answer below discusses).

Comment: @Cthulhu : plz see the solution that i hav posted

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Your code is incorrect for larger strings. `"123456789"` on reversal yields `"987456321"`

Comment: The last edit has significantly lowered that quality of the question. POOJA GUPTA, why do you think it makes sense to loop to `sqrt(len)`? If you're reverting a string of length 100, your code will only revert the first 10 characters, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig: u are right on ur part but I just mentioned one of the ways to reverse a string. Since u wanted to know how can we use sqrt function here, so I have posted the code snippet see to it .... :)

Comment: @user4815162342 : eh .... yes u r right ... i thought of this solution once and it worked .... thanks for correcting me ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "time complexity" you're referring to the big-O notation which excludes coefficients and lower-order terms, you will not be able to beat a simple O(n) algorithm for reversing a C string.

If you're referring to the time it takes for a specific machine (or class of machines) to execute the operation, there is a number of approaches to optimize the reversal. Typical optimizations include [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding), consuming the characters [machine word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) by machine word instead of character by character, and a smart search for the terminating NUL character. The freely available GNU libc contains [examples of such optimizations](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strchr.c;h=9d18b7eeb989c678d2c2e26eb067f7050dfaa126;hb=HEAD).

Some of the above optimizations, such as loop unrolling, may be automatically implemented by optimizing compilers. Others may be counter-productive on some platforms, or their speedup dependent on the size of the string. In some cases hand-written optimization can hinder the compiler's own effort to optimize the code. The only way to be sure you're not making things worse, develop a benchmark that covers your intended usage and meticulously benchmark your code as you progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(fctr=0,bctr=len-1;fctr<len/2;fctr++,bctr--)
{ 
    temp=str[fctr];
    str[fctr]=str[bctr];
    str[bctr]=temp;
}
```

this may work fast!